# HAProxy usage with kubernetes

Tags: haproxy, kubernetes

I am trying to setup a kubernetes cluster using HAProxy. Right now there are only two nodes. The loadbalancer is on the master node. But i see from the logs that the connection is tried on a virtual ip that is not present. Here are the endpoints for kubernetes cluster.

```
NAME                       ENDPOINTS                                                     AGE
activemq-svc               10.0.86.2:1883,10.0.86.2:8161,10.0.86.2:8161 + 1 more...      2h
admin-svc                  10.0.86.7:8080,10.0.86.7:9840,10.0.86.7:9841                  2h
kube-dns                   10.0.54.2:53,10.0.54.2:4001,10.0.54.2:53                      2h
kubernetes                 172.31.16.18:6443                                             4h
mysql-admin-svc            10.0.86.6:3306                                                2h
mysql-edu-svc              10.0.86.4:10050,10.0.86.4:3306                                2h
mysql-stat-svc             10.0.54.4:3306                                                2h
platform-riak-cs-service   10.0.54.3:8087,10.0.54.3:8080,10.0.54.3:8098                  2h
redis-svc                  10.0.86.3:6379                                                2h
server-svc                 10.0.86.10:8080,10.0.86.10:9840,10.0.86.10:9841 + 1 more...   2h
statistics-svc             10.0.86.8:8080,10.0.86.8:9840,10.0.86.8:9841                  2h
```

But in logs I see that my ip address tries to connect on an address that is not present in endpoint list. There is no rule in HAProxy.cfg also for *.*.86.5. Can someone please tell me whats happening?

```
servicelb [INFO] Connect from 118.102.239.85:39812 to **10.0.86.5:443** (httpsfrontend/HTTP)
servicelb [INFO] Connect from 118.102.239.85:40418 to 10.0.86.5:443 (httpsfrontend/HTTP)
servicelb [INFO] Connect from 118.102.239.85:41057 to 10.0.86.5:443 (httpsfrontend/HTTP)
servicelb [INFO] Connect from 118.102.239.85:41100 to 10.0.86.5:443 (httpsfrontend/HTTP)
servicelb [INFO] Connect from 118.102.239.85:41143 to 10.0.86.5:443 (httpsfrontend/HTTP)
servicelb [INFO] Connect from 10.0.86.1:49589 to 10.0.86.5:80 (httpfrontend/HTTP)
servicelb [INFO] Connect from 10.0.86.1:49611 to 10.0.86.5:80 (httpfrontend/HTTP)
servicelb [INFO] Connect from 10.0.86.10:53882 to 10.0.86.5:80 (httpfrontend/HTTP)
servicelb [INFO] 10.0.86.10:55668 [21/Dec/2015:11:45:15.526] httpsfrontend/1: SSL handshake failure
```

Answer (score 1):

That is normal, when you create a service, `kube-proxy` create in every node an iptables rule to redirect the traffic to endpoints, so using a cloud provider you will have the following scheme.

```
{external load balancer ip:port}->{NodePort(iptables PREROUTING RULE by kubeproxy)}->{pod internal ip address}
```

So you don't need to have the internal cluster service ip configured.

Answer (score 0):

The kube-proxy endpoint does TCP end-to-end proxying by default so IP addresses are lost.

If you activate the IP tables based proxy instead:

https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/scale-demo#activate-iptables-proxying